# how to remove UIButton from stackview if there is no content

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have four buttons in a stackView in a `collectionViewCell`

[image]

I am performing segue to a newVC if the button is tapped, the content i am displaying in the newVC is coming via JSON. If the url is empty or `url.characters.count == 0` for the respective button, i want to remove it from the cell and resize the rest of the buttons equally in the cell. How can i achieve that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616235-removearrangedsubview

Answer (score 1):

With `UIStackView` it is very simple. Just mark the button as hidden and the `UIStackView` will resize itself.

```
func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.isHidden = shouldHideButton()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}

func shouldHideButton() {
    ...
}
```

Also as [venkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571232/venkat) mentioned you can use `removeArrangedSubview(_:)` instead of just hiding, which will remove the button permanently.

I recommand you to read `UIStackView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in a `StackView`, the other items inside it will automatically adjust when we hide your `UIButton`.

In order to hide you `UIButton` based on your URL's character count, we can do the following:

```
button.isHidden = url.characters.count == 0
```

To simplify even further, we can just check for `.isEmpty` like so:

```
button.isHidden = url.isEmpty
```